# Generating a normalized matrix of random numbers which rows are generated from different Gaussian (normal) distributions

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, normal-distribution

I am trying to write a generator in python which generates a N*M matrix of random numbers using gaussian (normal) distribution.

given is N and M and the number of Gaussian random fields (normal distribution). The numbers in the matrix should also be between 0 and 1.
For example, a 100 * 80 matrix of float numbers between 0 and 1, which are generated from 5 different Gaussian distributions. The mean and variance of these distributions can be chosen arbitrarily. It is also arbitrary which and how many rows are generated by which distribution. The important thing is that the numbers in a row are generated in the same normal distribution. (Or rather, each row is a point that exists in a specific multivariate gaussian distribution)

I have already tried `scipy.stats.truncnorm`. Here I do not know how to generate the rows by different distribution and `num.random.multivariate_normal` is too complex to understanding. I have been looking for a long time and can find neither a good possibility to pass the restriction with the numbers between 0 and 1 nor find a way to generate the numbers from different normal distributions.

Comment: Welcome, please  elaborate a little. Give us a small sample of your expected output and your input. Do you want to generate a random matrix where each element is randomly chosen from five normal distributions and "clip" them between 0 and 1?

Comment: Have you considered creating the 5 different distributions as individual arrays, then using numpy `vstack` or `concatenate` to combine them into a single array (matrix)?

Comment: @kcw78 I know that i can generate arrays with `numpy.random.randn` and arbitrary _sigma_ and _mu_ but I dont know how I can solve that ristriction  with  having  numbers between 0 and 1.

Comment: @Mstaino Input: N (number of rows) , M (number of columns), x= number of different normal distribution with differen _sigma_ and _mu_ ; Output: a N*M Matrix, that the row _r1_ is generated from normal distribution with _sigma1_ and _mu1_, row _r2_ is generated from normal distribution with _sigma2_ and _mu2_ and etc. ristriction: the elements of matrix are numbers _n_ with 0<_n_<1 like [0.12 , 0.19, 0.39].

Comment: Normalize the array: find the max in the returned array with `numpy.amax` then divide. Or try `numpy.random.standard_normal`. It returns values with mean=0, and std_dev=1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that you already have `sigma` and `mu` (indicating which row will be using which distribution):

```
sigma = np.array((1, 2, 3))
mu = np.array((-1, -2, -3))
```

Just build the resulting distribution (3 rows/different disctributions, 10 columns here):

```
samples = np.random.standard_normal((3, 10)) * sigma[:, None] + mu[:, None]
```

Be aware that Gaussian distribution are unbounded, so you have to clip:

```
samples = np.clip(samples, 0, 1)
```

Of course, depending on the values of `sigma` and `mu`, you won't get Gaussian distributions of your values.

Comment: No, it's a Gaussian distribution, the numbers will be given between -inf and +inf by definition of the Gaussian distribution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there any other way to have 0 < _samples_ < 1 besides clipping?